# cakephp pre populate multiple multiple forms in single view

Tags: php, cakephp, populate

I have one problem with cakephp. I searched the whole site but do not find a proper solution.

So first let see. Pre populating form works best with form helper:

```
$this->request->data = $this->Model->find();
```

The above code populates the form but what if we have two forms with two models name?

```
 $this->Form->create('Basic');
```

and

```
$this->Form->create('Personal');
```

on the view of Profile

```
class ProfileController extends Appcontroller{
   public function index(){

       $this->request->data = $this->Basic->find();
       $this->request->data = $this->Personal->find();
    }
```

}

This code pre fill the second form not the first and if I remove the second line it fills the first form
So any solution to pre populate multiple forms in a single view?

Comment: Basic PHP: You cannot overwrite properties and expect them to be merged - magically.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not magic.
You need to either merge the data before-hand, or assign it to subkeys:

```
$basic = $this->Basic->find('first');
$personal = $this->Personal->find('first');

$this->request->data['Basic'] = $basic['Basic'];
$this->request->data['Personal'] = $personal['Personal'];
```

would work